# Understanding parsing of constructor initializer for template

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I'm trying to understand [a program demonstrating boost/spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/roman.cpp).

In the following template definition:

```cpp
template <typename Iterator>
struct roman : qi::grammar<Iterator,unsigned()> {
    roman() : roman::base_type(start)
    {
        using qi::eps;
        using qi::lit;
        using qi::_val;
        using qi::_1;
        using ascii::char_;

        start = eps[_val = 0] >>
            (
                +lit('M')[_val += 1000]
                ||  hundreds[_val += _1]
                ||  tens[_val += _1]
                ||  ones[_val += _1]
                )
            ;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator,unsigned()> start;
};
```

I'm trying to understand the meaning of `: roman::base_type(start)`.

- I assume it is a [constructor initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Function_definition).
- Furthermore, I assume that it is a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) and

  - that the member-initializer `roman::base_type(start)` initializes a base of `roman` called `base_type`
  - which is actually a `typedef` for `grammar<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>` from which `roman` inherits.

What I do not understand is how it could be initialized with `start` when `start` is a member of `roman`, the derived class we're still constructing?

Comment: Possibly the base class constructor needs just a reference to a `qi:rule<>` object to bind to it and does not use it immediately? Then the constructor can initialize the `start` member object, so it will be ready for use when the base class needs it.

Comment: @CiaPan Yes, that is correct the constructor only takes a reference: `grammar( rule<Iterator_, T1_, T2_, T3_, T4_> const&, std::string const& = "unnamed-grammar")`. So the addresses of the derived members are ready to be taken by reference while the bases are still being initialized?

Comment: Yes. The object is allocated first, then constructed, so during the `roman()` constructor prolog execution the `start` member is already allocated, thus the reference to it is already known. The functions can pass it around and store it safely, provided they don't try to dereference it (actually use the object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the narrative around the example in the documentation:

> 3. initialize the base grammar class by giving it the start rule (its the first rule that gets called when the grammar starts parsing)

Source: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/roman_numerals.html

It's passing a reference to the member. Although the member is not constructed at this time, the reference to it is valid. Provided the base class does not dereference the reference (i.e. only stores it or takes its address) then the code is legal... if a little 'dangerous'.

Comment: It seems almost ...magical. I like it, but is there a specific decree in standard that explains how the member addresses are usable at this point? Or did someone [make it legal](http://imgur.com/gallery/eKfQdxY)?

Comment: §9.2(2) is the closest I can find to a mention of this, coupled with the initialisation order rules, I believe it's inferable: A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing } of the classspecifier.
Within the class member-specification, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies,
default arguments, using-declarations introducing inheriting constructors (12.9), exception-specifications, and
brace-or-equal-initializer s for non-static data members (including such things in nested classes). Otherwise
it is regarded as incomplete...

Comment: Of course that's legal. You can take the address of a member as soon as there is an address of the containing object. Initialization comes later, and is no issue as long as the base doesn't presume to call methods on the reference during _it's construction_. There's even worse: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/utility/doc/html/base_from_member.html